# NodeJS and mongoDB with excel files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, excel, mongodb, xlsx

So I am building an App that needs to contain a functionality that accepts .xlsx file and convert it into JSON format, after converting it into JSON format I need to represent these data as a graph(bar chart, pie chart,etc).

I am a complete beginner and I don't know where to begin. If someone could give me   some advice regarding this I would be much grateful.

I am using React.JS for frontend and Nodejs MongoDB for backend.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the NPM packages. My personal favorite is https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx. Another for charts https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-chart